# Convert FeatureLayerClass to shapefile error: Item not found in collection

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-engine, shapefile, wpf, export

So following this link

http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/NET/91e3e8a0-d355-43d2-a201-0a8ceb719334.htm

I am able to convert my featureLayer into a shapefile and export it.

However, some how for 1 specific layer that I tested with I always get this error:

**Item NOT found in collection**

During this piece of code:

```
IFeatureDataConverter featureDataConverter = new FeatureDataConverterClass();
IEnumInvalidObject enumInvalidObject =
  featureDataConverter.ConvertFeatureClass(((IDataset)featureLayer.FeatureClass).FullName as IFeatureClassName,
  null, null, targetFeatureClassName, targetGeometryDef, targetFields, "", 1000, 0);

// Check for errors.
IInvalidObjectInfo invalidObjectInfo = null;
enumInvalidObject.Reset();
while ((invalidObjectInfo = enumInvalidObject.Next()) != null)
{
    // Handle the errors in a way appropriate to the application.
    Debug.WriteLine("Errors occurred for the following feature: {0}, {1}",
      invalidObjectInfo.InvalidObjectID, invalidObjectInfo.ErrorDescription);
    result = false;
}
```

It does not crash, but the enumInvalidObject always gives me the error `Item not found in this collection`.

Does anyone have an idea on what may cause this, I know saying that ONE of my layer don't work is very vague, but I really don't know what is special about that layer.

It does export the shapefile, but no features inside.